# How to tell what Framework a .Net web application needs to run under?

Tags: .net, iis, web-applications, .net-framework-version

We have a whole slew of custom written web applications on our company intranet.  We've had multiple developers at one time or another work on any one of them.  Over time we have gone to newer versions of Visual Studio as well.  We have some applications that are very old that never needed to be recompiled that still run on Framework version 1.1, some under 2, others 3xx.  We are getting an error message on IIS that "It is not possible to run two different versions of ASP.NET in the same IIS process" and then it causes a deadlock and hangs the server.  We have separate application pools created for each Framework version.  Since there are a number of apps running in any one of the app pools I need to isolate the app that is running under the wrong framework/app pool.  I would like to be able to check each and every .Net app to see what Framework version it is compiled to run under but I do not know how to tell by looking at the compiled dll or the config file, .vbproj or .csproj file, or what have you.  Can somebody tell me how I might be able to find this information for each of the apps running on our web server?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to see in web.config.  Are not you?

```
 <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
```